# Как правильно обрабатывать RuntimeException?

Tags: java, исключения, обработка-ошибок, exception-handler

Как правильно обрабатывать `RuntimeException`? Например, у меня есть следующий код:

```
if (file.exists() || file.mkdirs()) {
    // далее идёт запись в файл
}
```

Оба метода, `File.exists()` и `File.mkdirs()`, могут выбрасывать `SecurityException`, которая является подклассом `RuntimeException`. И насколько я знаю, `RuntimeException` нужно обрабатывать [особым образом](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html). Но всё-таки я не до конца понимаю, как именно их правильнее обрабатывать... Или правильнее их вообще не обрабатывать?
Т.е., в этом конкретном случае, какой вариант будет правильнее?

1) проверять только результат выполнения методов, без try-catch:

```
if (file.exists() || file.mkdirs()) {
   // запись в файл
}
```

2) проверять в try-catch:

```
try {
     if (file.exists() || file.mkdirs()) {
          // запись в файл
     }
          //...
} catch (e: SecurityException) {
          // обработка ошибки
}
```

Comment: Я правда, может неправильно понял суть вопроса

Comment: Нашел на просторах Сети [инфу](https://fox-code.ru/a/isklyucheniya-v-kotlin-kratkoe-rukovods/) по исключениям. Там вроде все расписано неплохо, может пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Написание того или иного кода зависит от того, какой уровень обработки ошибок вы хотите для своего приложения.

Если вы выберите первый способ, то приложение при исполнении просто выведет ошибку в лог или консоль. При этом человек разбирающийся в Java возможно и сможет определить суть проблемы и найти способ, как этой ошибки избежать. Однако это далеко не лучший способ, так как пользователь просто увидит `FileNotFoundException` или что-то вроде того.

Второй способ позволяет несколько доработать программу таким образом, чтобы она сама предпринимала действия в случае возникновения данной ошибки:

- Самый простой способ, это залогировать в данном блоке суть возникновения ошибки, например добавить код, который проверяет существует ли папка или файл, и затем выдать человеко-читаемый ответ, например, что файл по пути `./...` не найден.
- Другой вариант, позволить программе поискать данный файл в похожих или стандартных папках.

В общем случае, `try-catch` позволяет что-то сделать с тем, что в ходе исполнения программы возникла ошибка.

Конкретно в вашем случае, надо посмотреть на класс `SecurityException` и например дать совет пользователям, что они должны дать привелегии для чтения или записи по данному пути.

Answer (score 0):

Отлавливать `RuntimeException`, которое кидается не в вашем коде не имеет смысла. В приведенном описании по ссылке сказано, что такие исключения кидаются в случае если программа дальше не может работать.

Поэтому первый вариант вам больше подходит, но вы можете все-таки отлавливать такие исключения если у вас есть обработчик исключений.

Другое дело, если  `RuntimeException` кидается в вашем коде, и вы делаете это намеренно, по причине того, скажем, если нельзя использовать `Exception`. Тогда, такие исключения следует отлавливать на более высоком уровне, и кидать  `Exception`.