# Ругается обработчик ошибок, мол проблем с записью в БД быть не может

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch, sqlexception

Совершенно непонятно. Код, который просто записывает поля в БД

```
 if (findTypeIncRequestByName == null) {
      try {
            typeIncomingRequestRepo.save(typeIncomingRequest);// Пытаюсь записать в БД
            return "Способ связи " + typeIncomingRequest.getName() + " успешно добавлен";
           } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return "Database error";
           }
        } else {
            return "Способ связи " + typeIncomingRequest.getName() + " уже существует";
        }
```

Среда разработки мне подчеркивает `SQLException` и пишет что такой быть не может

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> "is never thrown in the corresponding try block"

Comment: Ну, раз пишут что нельзя - значит скорее всего так и есть. Попробуйте, например, заменить тип ошибки. На Exception или Throwable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Класс `SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) наследуется от `java.lang.Exception`, поэтому является *проверяемым* исключением. Если IJ показывает, что исключение не возникает в блоке try-catch, то, значит оно не возникает в блоке и во всех вызовах из блока, а также оно может быть перехвачено в вызываемом/ввполняемом коде.

Надо смотреть на метод `save()` и обрабатывать те исключения, которые у него записаны в определении throws.

Возможно у вас при вызове может возникать другое исключение, которое требуется отлавливать, к также если возникает *не проверяемое* исключение, то его можно отлавливать явно в блоке try-catch. В каких случаях нужно отлавливать такие исключения можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/901527/204920).