# Оборачивания checked исключения в unchecked

Tags: java, исключения, обработка-ошибок

Можете объяснить, зачем оборачивают `checked` исключения в `unchecked` в Java? Что это дает? Если не ошибаюсь не рекомендуется обрабатывать `unchecked` исключения.

Comment: Чтобы не марать методы интерфейсов "throws Exception". Это дает то, что потом, к примеру на FunctionalInterface можно красивую лямбду в одну строчку написать, а не городить реализацию с try-catch. Ошибаешься.

Answer (score 3):

Если ваш код вызывает исключения `checked`, то это значит, что вам надо их обрабатывать с помощью `try-catch` или вызывать глобальный обработчик исключений, который отлавливает эти исключения.

То есть если исключение не обрабатывается, то необходимо помечать метод как `throws` это исключение.

В некоторых случаях это невозможно, например, если метод перекрывает внешний интерфейс, в котором обработка исключений обязательна то нельзя изменить сигнатуру метода добавив `throws` и метод должен перекрывать метод интерфейса.

Если обернуть исключение как `unchecked`, то его можно будет отловить позже, но так делать нерекомендуется, потому что это позволяет не обрабатывать исключения, ну и программа перестает работать.

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/901527/204920), в этом ответе также идёт речь, как делать обратное, т.е. отлавливать `unchecked` исключения и оборачивать их в `checked`.

Чтобы понимать лучше чем отличаются `unchecked` исключения от `checked`, можно читать [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Вот что по этому поводу пишет  Oracle:

> «Если можно разумно ожидать, что клиент восстановится после исключения, сделайте его `checked` исключением.  Если клиент не может ничего сделать для восстановления после исключения, сделайте его `unchecked` исключением».

Поэтому оборачивать исключения одного типа в другой тип не рекомендуется, так как мы не можем изменить возможности клиента.