# Стоит ли кидать эксепшн в таких ситуациях?

Tags: java, spring

Надо ли в таком случае кидать эксепшн и вообще проверять такие ситуации?

Беру пользователя при помощи `@AuthenticationPrincipal` из контроллера -> передаю его в сервис чтобы сделать какое-то действие ( допустим, изменить пароль ) -> Надо ли кидать эксепшн, если такой пользователь не будет найден дальше в сервисе( даже ситуацию такую сложно приставить, ведь он только что был передан из контроллера )?

И где надо ловить такие ошибки. Прямо в сервисе или в контроллере?

Comment: Думаю надо почитать вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1349726/204920).